# Keycloak login timeout

Tags: spring-boot, web-applications, keycloak, kong, kong-oidc

I have a Spring Boot application connected to Kong Gateway in a microservices architecture through the Kong OIDC plugin. When I log out from the web application on a specific browser tab and already have another tab open in the same browser, I am successfully disconnected from both tabs and redirected to the Keycloak login page.

However, when I try to log in from the tab on which I performed the logout, I receive the following error from Keycloak: 'Your login attempt timed out. Login will start from the beginning. Login page:

[image]

Do you have any idea what could be the issue? I've also tried closing the other web application tabs when I log out from a specific tab, but without success."

Comment: I think the second tab overwrite an id or something like this on keycloak, the first tab send an old id so keycloak rejects it

Comment: Thanks for your reply do you have an idea how to resolve this issue  or can you give more details about this id ?